# Android on a stretched display (1920x480)?

Tags: screen

I'm trying to run the [unofficial android](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/) os on Raspberry Pi on a [screen similar](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/3256803881193198.html) to this one.

Before buying I wanted to know that if the android (in tablet mode) will adapt to the screen ratios? And if not, will there be anything that I will be able to do by editing the os?

I'm familiar with the screen dpi but that's not what I'm asking
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS19

> **Working**
>
> Touchscreen/multi-touch (official 7” touchscreen, USB touchscreens, Waveshare SPI touchscreens)

> **Q: My display is not working. I can only see the rainbow screen but no Android boot animation. What should I do?**
>
> A: This build only supports HDMI displays that report supported resolutions using EDID. 1920x1080 resolution is used by default with this build. **You can change value in /boot/resolution.txt to use a different resolution that your display supports.** Removing /boot/resolution.txt will use the preferred resolution of your display.

The link to the similar display does mention

> - If the monitor has a touch function, the USB cable needs to be directly connected to the USB interface with data transmission function of the Windows system host. At this time, the USB cable transmits power and touch signals.

And there is a section in the display link for Raspberry Pi operation:

> **Connect to Raspberry Pi:**
>
> When used on Raspberry Pi, you need to modify the "config.txt"
> Add the following code to the config.txt file:
>
> max_usb_current=1
>
> hdmi_group=2
>
> hdmi_mode=87
>
> hdmi_timings=400 0 100 10 140 1280 10 20 20 2 0 0 0 60 0 43000000 3
>
> Note: If it is Raspberry Pi 4, you also need to comment out dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-V3D.

There may be different settings for different displays. The ROM link indicates that you can make changes to /boot/config.txt